# Opening specific togglable tabs inside a Bootstrap 3 modal on clicking trigger buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) together in Bootstrap 3. My aim is to have 3 modal trigger buttons, each will open a different tab inside the modal.

[**My code so far**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WrtE/1/)

As you can see, all trigger buttons launch the modal but they all show `tab 1`. How can I make sure `tab 2` is shown when button 2 is clicked, and `tab 3` is shown when button 3 is clicked?

Comment: did you try href="#tab1" href="#tab2"?

Comment: I just did, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript methods for both in a click event handler:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    whichtab = $(this).data('opentab');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('.nav-tabs li:eq('+whichtab+') a').tab('show');
});
```

Instend of the data-toggle and data-target, I just added a data-opentab.  These are 0-based (so the first tab is 0, second is 1 etc.):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-opentab="0" >
  Launch modal - open tab 1
</button>
<br /><br /><br />
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-opentab="1" >
  Launch modal - open tab 2
</button>
<br /><br /><br />
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-opentab="2">
 Launch modal - open tab 3
</button>
```

Comment: this works but keep 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"' in the button

Comment: data-toggle and data-target are unnecessary if you are using the javascript method.

Comment: Spent the last 30 minutes testing this and it works flawlessly. Thanks!